# Chrome Extension / JavaScript Bookmarklet to trigger local script

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, cmd, bookmarklet

I programmed a local script to extract screenshots. The script takes an url as input parameter. Now I'd like to make a plugin/bookmarklet to trigger this local script which is located in c:/scripts/myscript.bat. Is this anyhow possible?

Answer (score 0):

The question is rather broad; so the answer is similarly broad.

It is possible with a Chrome Extension, if you use [Native Messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging). This is a shining-new documentation with fresh examples, thanks to [Rob W](https://stackoverflow.com/users/938089/rob-w).

It lets you execute a local program (as defined in the registry) and communicate with it over stdio. Unfortunately, you can't pass a command line parameter to it; you will have to implement the JSON-based protocol Chrome uses.